# How can I fill wall screw holes so I can reposition the screws?

Tags: walls, curtain-rail

I live in an old 1920's apartment building with thick solid walls and installed an ikea dignitet curtain wire. One side I've realized I've put in wrong and need to redrill two holes in a different position as it's coming loose in one position but I want to ensure that the wall around is solid in case the holes might overlap?

For reference this is what the fitting looks like. This is not mine and what I have put mine into is a solid wall.

[image]

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing the construction of the walls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "solid walls" meant in 1920's Germany but I'd guess it is either brick, concrete or building-blocks (aerated or aggregate blocks of varying density).

In general I've never found a way of filling such holes that would prevent a subsequent overlapping use of a masonry-drill from being deflected towards the old hole.

I'd consider

- enlarge the hole to include the new position, the fill it so that the drill encounters only homogeneous material.
- rotate the fitting 180 degrees.
- move it all 1 cm vertically and/or horizontally.
- use an intermediate mounting (e.g. a painted wooden plate)
- buy a different fitting.